# Fundo de página html com css

Tags: html5, css3

Olá tenho uma página que adicionei o msm css da outra página o da outra página tá certinho mas o dessa página a imagem fica só na metade da tela o resto fica preto olhem 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no Pc a msm coisa aqui está meu códico css

Todo meu códico HTML é esse

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>

 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="7f61e6b29ed1bdc580b02bb5e78b07a2.png" type="image/x-png">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<script type="text/javascript" src="source.js"></script>
<style>

html, body {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: url(scary_wolf-wide.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  background-position: 30% 45%;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;

 }

h3 { color:red; } h4 { color:red; font-size:30px; } 
body{ zoom: 100%; } footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0px;}
</style>

</head><body>

<h2>Área de login</h2>
<form name="login">
<center>
<fieldset>
<h3>Usuário:</h3>
<input type="text" id="username" size="20" />
<h3>Senha:</h3>
<input type="text" id="password" size="20" />
<br><input type="checkbox" id="lembrar-senha">Lembrar senha</br>
<br><input type="checkbox" id="bt-termos">Ao clicar você concordará com os termos e condições</br>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" id="bt-login" value="LOGIN" onclick="Login() "/>
</form></center>

<footer>
<a id="terms" href="dakota301.github.io/termos.html">Termos e condições</a>
<br><a href="dakota301.github.io/comprar_acesso.html">Comprar login</a></br>
</footer>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Acrescente `html` no seletor, assim: `html, body {`.

Comment: Eu fiz aqui cara mas não teve diferença não

Comment: Cara edita e coloca seu html na pergunta tb

Comment: Pronto já , só que não resolveu ainda "/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove html do bloco css:

remover -> **html,**

*Resultado:*

```
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: url(scary_wolf-wide.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
    background-position: 30% 45%;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    margin: 0
}
```

*Adiciona um novo bloco CSS:*

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Exemplo de resultado:

[Exemplo no scratchpad](http://scratchpad.io/lopsided-stem-2570) (**imagem de fundo usei uma qualquer**)

Comment: Sabe pq não consigo mostrar meu códico HTML aqui?

Comment: Deu certo man vlw tu é um gênio

Answer (score -2):

Seria interessante você criar o seu container ao invés de usar o body.

cria um ID  e atribua o seu css a esse ID.